# What are the eigenstates of $X^N$ operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

The operator $X$ is the position operator with it's conjugate being the momentum operator: $$[X,P]=i$$ ($\hbar=1$). Eigenstates of the position operator is known as quadrature/position states: $$X|x\rangle=x |x\rangle$$. But what about the eigenstates of the $X^N$ operator? Here $N$ is an integer greater than one. For example for $N=2$ we can say that superposition of the position operators are one of the eigenstates:

$$ X^2 (|x\rangle+|-x\rangle)=x^2 (|x\rangle+|-x\rangle)$$

As you can check. But also the position eigenstate is a $X^2$ eigenstate: $X^2|x\rangle =x^2 |x\rangle$.

Is there a general method or formula to find the complete set of eigenstates of $X^N$ in terms of the eigenstate of $X$?

Comment: If $|x\rangle$ is an eigenvector of any operator $X$. It is also an eigenvector of the operator $X^N$ for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I can't see what I am missing?

Comment: This is really just a maths question in physics notation. What you're missing is that eigenvectors with degenerate eigenvalues span an eigenspace of vectors.

Comment: Also somebody should probably make the point that at least in the usual situations $X$ doesn't have eigenvectors at all in the usual sense since the states $|x\rangle$ are not in our Hilbert space (I think they're in its closure? this has always confused me).

Comment: Then I should ask it on math.stackexchange.

Comment: 2 things.  (1) you |x> + |-x> state needs to be normalized (a minor point).  But (2) each of the states |x>, |-x> is an eigenstate of x^2n with the same eigenvalue.  That just means that there is degeneracy in the spectrum of x^2n.  You can also make (|x> - |-x>)/sqrt(2) as an eigenstate of that operator.

Comment: I have omitted the normalization for ease of reading, it is not relevant at all. I have mentioned the superposition eigenstate and I know that they are eigenstate of many other similar operators, however this doesn't tell anything about the all possible eigenstates.

Answer (score 1):

The [Borel Functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus) says that a self adjoint operator operator $X$ and the self-adjoint operator $f(X)$ have the same eigenstates for any reasonable function $f$.  The eigenvalues differ, of course.  If $|x \rangle$ is an eigenstate of $X$ with eigenvalue $x$, then $f(X)|x\rangle = f(x)|x\rangle$.

Comment: In addition, based on the answers I got from math.stackexchange, since the eigenvalues are degenerate combination of those that have the same eigenvalues are also eigenvectors.